# How is PAW Patrol funded?

Tags: economics, paw-patrol

I was watching *PAW Patrol* with my niece when I got to thinking that all of that advanced rescue equipment, all of those trucks, ATV's, helicopters, submarines, patrol boats, and other fancy vehicles, and, of course, the seemingly unlimited supply of pup treats can't be cheap.

Is it ever explained how the PAW Patrol is funded?

- Is PAW Patrol a government agency or contractor, funded through the municipal tax revenue of Adventure Bay?
- Is PAW Patrol privately funded by a wealthy philanthropist who mostly stays off-screen?
- Is Ryder independently wealthy and funding the PAW Patrol himself, a la *Batman* or *Iron Man*?
- Does PAW Patrol pay for all of its stuff by billing the people it rescues in each episode?

Comment: In the season 2 episode Pups Go for the Gold, the Prospector donates a gold nugget that is about a metre squared with an approximately value of about half a billion dollars. https://pawpatrol.fandom.com/wiki/Pups_Go_for_the_Gold?file=Pups_Go_for_the_Gold_%28HQ%29.png. This is far from the first incredibly valuable item found or rescued by the pups.

Comment: An Instagram page with cute puppy pictures…

Comment: @Valorum Wow. Is... is there *any* piece of scifi-fantasy you're *not* fluent in?? Also, its more like a meter *cubed*.

Comment: @RMF - Yep. That

Comment: _FOLLOW THE MONEY_ 

Comment: I've seen more than one person suggesting that the heroic, and frankly unlikely, nature of Ryder's existence suggests that he's (perhaps unknowingly) living in a virtual reality environment.

Comment: I'm waiting on Ryder to be brought up for illegal generic experiments . . . also, apparently the pups never age . . .

Comment: I never expected to see a question about _funding_ for a show where pups talk and pilot vehicles like humans, and are led by a 10-year old boy ;)

Answer (score 19):

We learn in *[Paw Patrol: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAW_Patrol:_The_Movie)* that at least some of their funding comes from merchandising when Skye asks how they can afford their new HQ.

> **Ryder:** *Welcome to our new Adventure City headquarters.*
>
> **Skye:** *Whoa! Wow! Awesome! Now that's a view! Whoa! How can we afford this place?*

Ryder explains that he sells officially licensed Paw Patrol merchandise (holding up a T-Shirt as an example) explaining that they "*sell like hotcakes*".

> **Ryder:** *Officially licensed PAW Patrol merchandise. This stuff sells like hot cakes!*

Comment: You'd need to sell a lot of keyrings and hats to fund a helicopter, a submarine and a plane :-)

Comment: Oh, I've probably funded a drone or two :).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the movie quotes.

Comment: "*BRUNKER: Without giving away the joke, one of the questions from parents always is, **“How does the PAW Patrol pay for all these things? They have towers and vehicles and gadgets. Who’s bankrolling this thing?” And so, we answered that question in the movie with a joke**, and we didn’t think our partners would let us keep that in, but they loved it. They thought it was hilarious. They’ve got a good sense of humor about the whole thing. Without saying what that is, you can find out, if you watch the movie, how they bankroll all of their gear.*" - https://tinyurl.com/9bwcy9ye

Answer (score 17):

All signs point to the Paw Patrol being funded by the town governance of Adventure Bay, noting that they perform the combined tasks of the (curiously absent) Police, Ambulance Service, Fire Service, Mountain Rescue and Coastguard.

On multiple occasions their activities have resulted in a significant cash influx for the town, far exceeding any realistic cost of their gadgets, vehicles, training and HQ.

---

> Recovered [Captain Blackfur's treasure chest](https://pawpatrol.fandom.com/wiki/Pups_and_the_Pirate_Treasure) (Estimated value = $100,000,000 / Gifted to the 'People of Adventure Bay')
>
> [image]

> Helped [Prospector to secure his gold](https://pawpatrol.fandom.com/wiki/Pups_Save_a_Goldrush) (Estimated value = $800,000,000 / Bequeathed to the town in the form of a gigantic solid gold chicken)
>
> [image]

> Helped to recover [a significant amount of "golden bones"](https://pawpatrol.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Rescue:_Pups_and_the_Hidden_Golden_Bones) - Estimated value $5,000,000,000,000 / Taken into possession by the Mayor and stored under City Hall)
>
> [image]

Comment: Just, wow ... is there no part of pop culture that you're unfamiliar with? Are you in fact an AI that was trained upon the entire corpus of works of fiction: all genres, books, movies, TV alike? [if so, then the question to put to the AI is: what is the title of the first work to feature a pop-culture-maven AI?]

Comment: Adventure Town would likely experience significant price inflation due to the massive influx of gold, similar to Spain during the conquest of the Aztecs and Inca

Answer (score -1):

In Nick jr videos and Pups Save A Fix, is says that ryder and rocky built Robo dog. its possible most of their gadgets and vehicles were from old scrap metal and rocky and ryder built them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you mean [Pups in a Fix](https://pawpatrol.fandom.com/wiki/Pups_in_a_Fix)?