# Origin story for Paw Patrol

Tags: paw-patrol

My two year old son has just gotten obsessed with Paw Patrol and I have been forced to watch a number of mind-numbing episodes with him.

While watching, I started wondering: How did a ten year old boy end up in charge of super-effective robot enhanced dogs? Is there an origin story for how Ryder started Paw Patrol?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, the original pitch had them being rescued dogs that became rescue dogs, but that apparently got dropped before the first episode aired.

Comment: Not to mention the millions of dollars in high-tech equipment.  I've often asked the same question myself.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251581/how-is-paw-patrol-funded?rq=1 partially explains the equipment, namely that the Paw Patrol keeps finding treasure.

Comment: Excuse me, but Ryder is _eleven_!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots some that seems to have stayed, we know Rubble and Everest were strays (or whatever they call them in the show... they didn't have owners/family).

Comment: Ryder is actually bruce wayne minus the bat obsession and instead a dog obsession

Comment: _DEFUND PAW PATROL_

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It looks like the show purposely doesn't have a back-story; https://www.theglobeandmail.com/arts/television/whats-paw-patrols-secret-how-it-captivated-children-and-conquered-theworld/article37417532/

Comment: Try *Sarah & Duck*, *If You Give A Mouse A Cookie*, or *Bluey* for cartoons with something resembling plot and character.  None of them have superpowers, but cute animals guaranteed.

Comment: @Valorum that should be a good answer.